# (python) Accessing nested value on JSON if list not empty,

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, nested

Im trying to access json value and only print 'tourList' that not empty

```
import json
json_obj = {
"STATUS": "SUCCESS",
"DATA": {
    "data": [
        {
            "destinationId": "36",
            "name": "Bali ",
            "destinationCode": "DPS",
            "tourList": []
        },
        {
            "destinationId": "216",
            "name": "Bandung",
            "destinationCode": "24417",
            "tourList": []
        },
        {
            "destinationId": "54",
            "name": "Batam",
            "destinationCode": "BTH",
            "tourList": [
                {
                    "tourId": "20586",
                    "tourCode": "IDBTH00585",
                    "tourName": "BATAM SPECIAL SPA PACKAGE",           
                    "tourTime": [
                        {
                            "tourStartTime": "09:00:00",
                            "tourEndTime": "16:00:00",

                        }
                    ],
                    "pricing": [
                        {
                            "adultPrice": "193.00",
                            "tourId": "20586"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }          

    ]
 }
}

wanted = ['tourId', 'tourCode', 'tourName', 'tourTime','pricing']

for item in json_obj["DATA"]["data"]:
    details = item['tourList']
    if not details:
       print("")
    else:
        for key in wanted:
            print(key, ':', json.dumps(details[key], indent=4))
            #Put a blank line at the end of the details for each item
            print()
```

and then i got this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "testapi.py", line 57, in 
>     print(key, ':', json.dumps(details[key], indent=4))
>     TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

im thinking that error because some of the tourList is empty, help me how to check tourList is empty and then only print tourList that is not empty

also can you help me so that the result is like this

```
tourId : "20586"
tourCode : "IDBTH00585"
tourName : "BATAM SPECIAL SPA PACKAGE"
tourStartTime: "09:00:00"
tourEndTime: "16:00:00"
adultPrice: "193.00"
tourId: "20586"
```

Comment: details = item['tourList'][0] to get the dictionary before you try to access the key

Comment: Your `details` is referencing a list of ` tourList`, that's why your `details[key]` is failing because it's expecting the index of a list, not the key of a dictionary as you expected.  Edit: what Krishna said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`details` (`item['tourList']`) is `list` of `dicts`, not a `dict` itself. Change to:

```
for d in details:
    for key in wanted:
        print(key, ':', json.dumps(d[key], indent=4))
```

Or if you only want the first `dict` in said `list`:

```
for key in wanted:
    print(key, ':', json.dumps(details[0][key], indent=4))
```

Comment: done, thanks :)

also can you help me so that the result is like this
tourId : "20586"
tourCode : "IDBTH00585"
tourName : "BATAM SPECIAL SPA PACKAGE"
"tourStartTime": "09:00:00"
"tourEndTime": "16:00:00"
"adultPrice": "193.00",
"tourId": "20586"

Comment: That's a new question ;) you have to find a way to get down the nesting levels.

Answer (score -1):

Hope it may help you:

```
data = json_obj.get("DATA")
for key in data.keys():
    for get_list in data[key]:
        if not get_list.get('tourList'):
            print('Skip it')         
        else:
            print('Do Something')
```