# python help me to access json nested and make it looks better

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, nested

I need help to display a result like result number 2, Below is the full code for result number 1

```
import json
json_obj = {
"STATUS": "SUCCESS",
"DATA": {
    "data": [
        {
            "destinationId": "216",
            "name": "Bandung",
            "destinationCode": "24417",
            "tourList": []
        },
        {
            "destinationId": "54",
            "name": "Batam",
            "destinationCode": "BTH",
            "tourList": [
                {
                    "tourId": "20586",
                    "tourCode": "IDBTH00585",
                    "tourName": "BATAM SPECIAL SPA PACKAGE",           
                    "tourTime": [
                        {
                            "tourStartTime": "09:00:00",
                            "tourEndTime": "16:00:00",

                        }
                    ],
                    "pricing": [
                        {
                            "adultPrice": "193.00",
                            "tourId": "20586"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }          

    ]
 }
}

wanted = ['tourId', 'tourCode', 'tourName', 'tourTime','pricing']

for item in json_obj["DATA"]["data"]:
details = item['tourList']
if not details:
   pass 
else:
   #print(details['tourId'])
  for d in details:
   for key in wanted:
    print(key, ':', json.dumps(d[key], indent=4))

    #Put a blank line at the end of the details for each item
   print()
```

Result Number 1
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmzsS.png)

how can i edit the code so the result is like result number 2, just make it become nice to read like result number 2

Result Number 2

```
tourId : "20586"
tourCode : "IDBTH00585"
tourName : "BATAM SPECIAL SPA PACKAGE"
tourStartTime: "09:00:00"
tourEndTime: "16:00:00"
adultPrice: "193.00"
tourId: "20586"
```

also 1 more question, can i edit the name of json value into our own string
example(tourId : "20586") to (Tour ID : 20586)

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e08db6d48bd83fcac60ed88c517ffffc

Comment: Are you two in the same class? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48181747/python-accessing-nested-value-on-json-if-list-not-empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(python) Accessing nested value on JSON if list not empty,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48181747/python-accessing-nested-value-on-json-if-list-not-empty)

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't post urls to pictures. Include the pictures themselfs in the posting. Please use correct interpunction and upper case letters. Please reformulate what you really want. What is your goal. It is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve your 2 questions (use 1 only) is to alter your `wanted` and include a new `rewriteDic` to replace keys with other values. For parts of `wanted` that are `dict()` we handle printing outself. Implicit format for that is a set that takes a list of subkeys, only subkeys will be printed in that case. This is tailored to your given JSON, test with other output before using and adapt accordingly. If we encounter a key that is given inside `rewriteDic` we use the value there for printing instead of the "real" key:

Code is commented to explain what's being done:

```
wanted = ['tourId', 'tourCode', 'tourName', 
          {'tourTime':['tourStartTime','tourEndTime']}, # if we encounter a dict we change
          {'pricing':['adultPrice','tourId']}           # the printing mechanics
         ]

rewriteDic = {'tourId':'Tour ID', 'tourCode':'Super Douper Cool and Secret ID Code'}

for item in json_obj["DATA"]["data"]:
    details = item['tourList']
    if not details:
        pass 
    else:
        #print(details['tourId'])
        for d in details:
            for key in wanted:
                if isinstance(key, dict): # got a dict, so our "wanted" contains the real
                    for sub in key:       # subkeys as list as value inside the dict
                        subKeys = key[sub]       # this is what we want to print 
                        for sKey in subKeys:     # so for all that are in 
                            # ask rewriteDic for the value of sKey, else use sKey
                            print( rewriteDic.get(sKey,sKey),":",d[sub][0][sKey])

                else:
                    # Edit: apply rewriteDic here too: 
                    # print(key, ':', json.dumps(d[key], indent=4))
                print(rewriteDic.get(key,key),':',d[key])

        # Put a blank line at the end of the details for each item
        print()
```

Output:

```
Tour ID : 20586
Super Douper Cool and Secret ID Code : IDBTH00585
tourName : BATAM SPECIAL SPA PACKAGE
tourStartTime : 09:00:00
tourEndTime : 16:00:00
adultPrice : 193.00
Tour ID : 20586
```

Comment: why when i add rewriteDic = {'tourId':'Tour ID','tourCode':'Tour Code'}
the output did not change to Tour Code